# assembly language function 2 looping

Tags: assembly

I am trying to figure out how to loop through a string one character at time, using my cursor.
 The program that I made was able to grab a certain index in in the string.
However, how can I loop through the entire string one character at a time?

```
title Hello World Program (hello3.asm)

;
; This is the sample program on page 572 of your text with little modification
;It utilizes Dos service 40h.
;

.model small
.data
    message db "Hello, Dos Here!",0dh,0ah,'$'


.code
main proc
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    mov cx, 5
L1:
    mov ah, 2
    mov dl, message
    int 21h

loop L1
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
main endp
end
```

`

Comment: What does this code do? Which assembler? Why do you write `mov dl,message`? How do you think characters of string are stored in computer memory?

Comment: @Ped7g the code prints out the first character of the string 5 times and what i am trying to figure out how can i get the string to print one character a time

Comment: Put the address of the string in a register, and increment it at the end of each iteration (note that not all registers can be used in an effective address in 16-bit code).

Comment: So how do you think the string is stored in computer? Obviously in memory. There are many common ways, how to manipulate with memory content. I wonder what kind of book needs 572 pages not even explaining how computer works... :D

Comment: Mike, there's a new answer to your question, check it out!

Comment: DOS calls? How do you run this?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Michael, you need to put the address of the string in a register, for example, `SI`, then increase `SI` one byte (one char) at a time. When char '$' is reached, the loop must finish:

```
.model small
.data
    message db "Hello, Dos Here!",0dh,0ah,'$'

.code
main proc
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

;   mov cx, 5                    ;<=== WE DON'T NEED CX BECAUSE WE AREN'T
                                 ;     USING THE LENGTH OF THE STRING, WE
                                 ;     ARE USING THE '$' CHAR.
    mov si, offset message       ;<=== SI POINTS TO FIRST CHARACTER OF STRING.
L1:
;CHECK IF '$' (LAST CHAR) IS THE CURRENT CHAR.
    mov dl, [si]                 ;<=== CURRENT CHARACTER TO PRINT.
    cmp dl, '$'                  ;<=== IF CURRENT CHAR IS '$'...
    je  finish                   ;<=== ... JUMP TO FINISH.
;PRINT CHAR IN DL.  
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h          
;loop L1                         ;<=== WE DON'T NEED LOOP BECAUSE
                                 ;     WE ARE NOT USING CX.
    inc si                       ;<=== NEXT CHAR OF THE STRING.
    jmp L1                       ;<=== REPEAT.

finish:

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
main endp
end
```